# Load a Prolog database file (.pl) through gprolog (GNU Prolog)

Tags: database, prolog, load

Within the GNU Prolog (Daniel Diaz, http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html), how do we open a pl file containing data without knowing the cwd of GProlog?

I know that there are two possibilities:

- [*name of the file*].,
- Prolog built-in function consult('*name of the file*')..

I know that I must put the .pl file in the cwd of gprolog, but what is the command in gprolog to find the cwd or what is command to say to gprolog 'Go find this file and open it'?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I know that I must put the .pl file in the cwd of gprolog*. That's actually not true. Even if it was, you would not need to determine the cwd in Prolog in order to load the file if you know the file is already in your cwd. You would just load it without specifying a path.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the answer:

1. In Gprolog: type ['*absolute path of your .pl file*'] or ['*relative path of your .pl file*']
2. Launch Gprolog in your terminal where is located your .pl file.